# Empty hard drive when mounted in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

I mounted a previous hard drive had had mounted on a previously installed Ubuntu server version 12.

I then upgraded and installed Ubuntu 13 and when I mount the same hard drive, the contents of the device is empty.

Executing `df -H` shows me this:

```
/dev/sda        3.0T  1.5T  1.4T  52% /dataDrive
```

And `fdisk -l` tells me this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sda doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

As you can see, half of the hard drive have data inside it but when I navigate to `/dataDrive` and type in `ls`, its empty?

The drive in question has been formatted to a Linux partition previously.

Any ideas why I can’t access my files?

Answer (score 0):

`fdisk` can only see MBR partitions and not GPT partitions.  Try `gdisk` to list GPT partitions.  The syntax is the same as `fdisk`.

Assuming GPT partitions are in use, you should see them listed out.  Now changing your mount command to mount the appropriate partition.  It looks like you are trying to mount the drive and not a partition which is not what you want unless you are doing something really weird like accessing the drive raw.  Your mount command and subsequently the output from your `df` command should list the drive and partition number such as `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sda3`, etc.

If, after trying the above, there is still no partition table detected, you may have to rebuild them.  Download `testdisk` to a spare system and have it scan the problem drive to see if it can locate the signs of the partition tables and file system.  If it is successfully able to rebuild the tables, you can test the new tables by browsing files on the disk, and when satisfied write the tables permanently to disk.

Comment: Hi. i tried the following below:

gdisk /dev/sda

output below:

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.7

Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries.

Comment: Hopefully you didn't commit the new GPT entries.  See update above.